# здравствуйте, помогите растянуть анимацию <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas> поверх на весь блок

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="large-header">
<canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<section>
<h4>АО</h4>
<h1>Коммунальник</h1> <a href="site/index.html" style="margin-top:    6.5em; 
margin-left: 50%;">на главную</a>
</section>
<style>
    *{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body {
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.8);
color: white;
font-family: helvetica;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
section {
display: grid;
grid-template-column: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-row: 1fr 1fr 120px;
grid-gap: 1rem;
margin: 30px;
}
section h4 {
font-size: 1.2em;
grid-column: 4 / -1;
grid-row: 1 / 2;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
section h1 {
grid-column: 3 / 4;
grid-row: 1 / 2;
font-size: 7em;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
padding-right: 5px;
}
section p {
grid-column: 1 / 2;
grid-row: 3 / 4;
font-size: 14px;
}
section a {
grid-row: 1 / 3;
grid-column: 2 / 4;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.5em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/animated.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [так ?](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dwxgGV?editors=1100)

Comment: хотя надо на js передавать innerWidth и innerHeight в canvas

Comment: надо как на этом примере, только с моим фоном [https://codepen.io/JulianLaval/pen/KpLXOO]

Comment: спасибо. разобрался.